# Reboot / shutdown log

Tags: server, ssh, reboot, logs

On a 12.04 server, I have random reboot issues with my dedicated server, that I can only resolve through ssh.
Sometimes (usually after applying important security updates), I issue a reboot through ssh. The server becomes inaccessible (apache, ssh) but still responds to ping.

Most services seem to have shut down, but there server didn't reboot. In those situations, I have to request a manual reboot through the web interface (basically, they just cur the power).

And sometimes, it isn't enough. The server restarts, but again, no http, no SSH. I have to do a second manual reboot.
After that, I can issue many reboot through SSH, with no config change, and the server will work. Until next time.

I am under the impression that this "reboot" issue only appears when I haven't rebooted for some time (several days/weeks).

**How can I investigate this issue ?**

I have tried looking at kernel.log

The last failed ssh reboot was around 15:10
The manual reboot was at 15:32.

```
Jun 22 16:20:52 server1 kernel: [579427.072541] UDP: bad checksum. From 71.6.135.131:40000 to 37.187.100.21:161 ulen 51
Jun 23 15:10:19 server1 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.0-64-generic (buildd@kissel) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 22:04:21 UTC 2014 (Ubuntu 3.2.0-64.97-generic 3.2.59)
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-64-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jun 23 15:32:05 server1 kernel: [    0.000000] Disabled fast string operations
```

Comment: You should check your syslog, kern.log, dmesg, keep an eye on your file systems, check your disks for problems, ram, ... 
Also keep in mind that for remote servers, it's always handy if you have a remote access card (like DRAC, ILO, etc). This will save you tons of money / time with problems like this. Cutting power can always cause problems with your data and hardware.

Comment: I said cut power, but I don't know what they have. The server is hosted by a private company (OVH) I reboot using the web interface. But since their recommendation is that this way is a last resort, I guess it might not be nice for the server. Thank you for your reply. I will start by checking the logs. There is nothing in kern.log. How can I see the last messages written in any of the logs prior to rebooting?

Comment: In your log files, you will see a lot of messages about services that are being "started" at reboot. Just search for the keyword "started"

Answer (score -1):

Try update your system or your services.

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

do-release-upgrade

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would rather NOT upgrade to 14.04. Simulations I did run show multiple issues regarding the config files of the server. Some scenario also show the server not rebooting properly at all. So your solution could cost me a lot of money (if human intervention is required). I would prefer to investigate the issue. *where is the server blocking* in the reboot process...